# Header image bottom border

Tags: css

I added a bottom border to the header image on my Phorum template, so that it would look like the top black line on the page.  However, its not starting at the far left of the block like the top one is, and when I extend its width, it goes right...but not left.  I'm trying to make it identical to the one on top, just below the header image.  Any ideas?

www.cigarcache.com/forum

```
#phorum #header {
margin: -8px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#phorum #header img {
margin: 0px;
}

#phorum #header_bottom_gap {
height: 15px;
}

#phorum #logobottom {
border-bottom: 1px solid {breadcrumb_border_color};
}


<div id="header">
<div id="logobottom"><a href="http://www.cigarcache.com"><img
src="{URL->TEMPLATE}/images/header.png"
width="{header_width}" height="{header_height}" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
</div>
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest solution would be to cut the whole header div out of #body-main and paste it above #body-main and tweak the styles a bit.

```
#phorum #logobottom {
/*border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
}

#phorum #header {
margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding:0 38px;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly Slave.  Only other thing I had to do was move the search box elements above #body-main as well.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

`#body-main` has padding of 38px left and right - Thats why there is a gap.